# How to get i18n translate function to the plugin in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, plugins, vuejs2

I have a **Vue 2** project. This contains `i18n` plugin to translate. I can use it in components like `this.$t('path.to.msg')` but I dont know how to access it in other plugin.

Vue documentation says import Vue and then use it like `Vue.somePlugin()`. But it does not work like `Vue.t()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Vue i18n translation in .js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831314/how-to-use-vue-i18n-translation-in-js-file)